# Open Chrome NodeJS Debugger in a Tab instead of a New window

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to open the Chrome NodeJS debugger after running `node --inspect-brk` and going to `chrome://inspect` in a Tab instead of a standalone Window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
~$ curl http://localhost:9229/json/list 
[ {
  "description": "node.js instance",
  "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9229/043a8dfa-cd2b-4d41-82db-740a9d332499",
  "faviconUrl": "https://nodejs.org/static/favicon.ico",
  "id": "043a8dfa-cd2b-4d41-82db-740a9d332499",
  "title": "/Users/josh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node",
  "type": "node",
  "url": "file://",
  "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9229/043a8dfa-cd2b-4d41-82db-740a9d332499"
} ]
```

Open the `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9229/043a8dfa-cd2b-4d41-82db-740a9d332499` URL in a Chrome tab.

The [Inspector Help](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/) page links to a Chrome extension that purports to open this link automatically, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: What node version are you using? `devtoolsFrontendUrl` is not present when I do the curl, but the extension is working! Im using v8.9.1

Comment: Also 8.9.1. I don't know what the difference could be.

Comment: On macOS you can execute the following (Provided you have `jq` installed): `open -a 'Microsoft Edge.app' "$( curl -sSf htt
p://localhost:9229/json/list | jq -r '.[0].devtoolsFrontendUrl' )"`
You could change `Microsoft Edge.app` for `Chrome.app` or another Chromium browser app

Answer (score 1):

This extension worked for me

[image]

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj/related?hl=en

It supports opening in a tab and reconnecting automatically. It's add supported.